# Using KNN for pattern matching of time series

Tags: r, pattern-matching, pattern-recognition, knn

I want to try to implement a KNN algorithm for pattern matching (or pattern recognision) in my time series data. The data are of consumption measurements. I've got a table with some columns, where the first column is datetime of the measurement and the other columns represent the measurements. There is one example:

```
datetime             mains           stove  kitchen microwave TV
2013-04-21 14:22:13 341.03             6      57         5     0
2013-04-21 14:22:16 342.36             6      57         5     0
2013-04-21 14:22:20 342.52             6      58         5     0
2013-04-21 14:22:23 342.07             6      57         5     0
2013-04-21 14:22:26 341.77             6      57         5     0
2013-04-21 14:22:30 341.66             6      55         5     0
```

I want to use the KNN algorithm to compare the pattern of the mains signal with the patterns of other signals. So my training set would consist of labeled measurements of every appliance and the test data set would consist of the mains signal measurements. The aim of this is to detect changes in the signal - which appliance was turned on in which time.

What I actually want to ask is:

- how to cope with the datetime format? In which format should it be passed to KNN? (I wonder there will be some conversion to integer or normalization?)
- is the KNN algorithm suitable for this task?
- how to generally perform pattern matching with KNN?

What I've already tried - I tried to put single vector consisting of labeled patterns of data (of each appliance) to the KNN as the training set and then put mains data as the test set. I totally omitted the datetime column. I've got bad resuls.

I'm implementing this in R language.

Any ideas?

Comment: What types of variables are the stove, kitchen, microwave, and TV variables?  What do they represent?  What does the mains variable roughly represent?

Comment: All of the variables are values of measurements. That means, for example, in 2013-04-21 14:22:13, the total energy consumption was 341.03 W (the mains value), stove consumed 6W, kitchen appliances 57W, and so on.

Comment: And what is it exactly that you are trying to figure out?